# What is the fastest way to backup external harddisk

Tags: windows, backup, external-hard-drive

I came across various free tools such as Macrium Reflect.

May I know does Macrium free version provides "resume" capability? As my current HDD contains a lots of files and folder which I believed it will take quite long to complete.

I also came across another tool called TeraCopy. Anyone tried that? Is it really faster and secure?

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

TeraCopy is about the same as Windows' [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) in speed, but it does lots more of what you don't need *and* it hooks into the system in non-obvious ways. The only real benefit is that it has GUI while `robocopy` is command-line and it may overwhelm a bit with [all its options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx).

But fear not, here's all you need -

```
robocopy X:\  Z:\Backup-of-X\ /MIR /Z /FFT
```

where `X:\` is your external drive you are backing up and `Z:\Backup-of-X\` is a directory where you want the backup to go.

`/MIR` tells it to create an exact copy of the tree, i.e. remove files from the backup that don't exist at the source.

`/Z` enables resumable copying of large files, so you can Ctrl-C robocopy half way through a large file and it will start copying from the second half on the next run.

`/FTT` tells it to assume 2-second timestamp resolution. This has to do with how robocopy detects which files have changed and which haven't. It's a long story, just use `/FFT`.

Answer (score 0):

If a filesystem-level copy is OK to you, teracopy seems me a good choice.

If you want a sector-by-sector copy (for example there are tricky non-windows partitions of your external drive, or you want to be able to boot from that), I used the commandline dd from the linux world.